# Reading HttpRequestMessage content. DelegatingHandler vs ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've read in a few places that it's impossible to read the contents of the request stream in WebApi more than once, as it's forward only. This presents a problem if you're trying to implement an AOP style request logger and you also want to dump the contents of a request.

I've been playing around with it, and I've noticed that if you try to read the stream in an ActionFilter.OnActionExecutingAsync, as below, you get problems with null content in the controllers action.

```
    public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnActionExecutingAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var content = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        traceManager.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, (int)EventId.RequestReceived, "{0}", content);
    }
```

Having said that, if you implement almost the same code in an DelegatingHandler:

```
     protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       traceManager.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, (int)EventId.RequestReceived, "{0}", content);

       return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

It works flawlessly and doesn't cause any problems with everything further down the pipeline. I understand that the handler runs much sooner than the filter, but why is it possible to do this at one stage of the pipeline but not another?